# mySQL tables: how do I get the file size reasonable and rational?

Tags: mysql

Can someone please shed some light on mySQL table sizes in relation to the actual size of the data ... and in particular, how to get the table size to something that "makes sense"?

I have a simple table definition with 14 fields, all numbers with a mixture of integer and floating types, total record size = 48 bytes, one integer index field.

Example: loading 5 of these tables using LOAD DATA INFILE. Number of records ranges from 22,000 to 37,000, total bytes of data ranges from 1.3MB to 1.8MB. The table sizes are all 10.24MB except the smallest one which is 9.2MB. Is this not insane? I understand there is file size overhead beyond the actual data, but >500%?

Comment: What table engine do you use? Have you had any previous data in the tables? Have you removed previous data from the tables?

Comment: These are brand new, freshly created tables. The only operation done on them is the one LOAD DATA INFILE. Not sure what you mean by "table engine", but I'm using ADO in VBA to execute the SQL ... but I get the same results using the mySQL command line.

Comment: table enginse: innodb, myisam, etc. Each store data differently, each has lots of config options.

Comment: I'm using innodb with each table in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

Innodb, in order to reduce the fragmentation of the data files, reserves larger blocks of data when the data file needs to grow and it stores the indexes within the tablespace as well. As mysql documentation on [innodb file space management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-space.html) says:

> Each tablespace consists of database pages. Every tablespace in a
>   MySQL instance has the same page size. By default, all tablespaces
>   have a page size of 16KB; you can reduce the page size to 8KB or 4KB
>   by specifying the innodb_page_size option when you create the MySQL
>   instance. As of MySQL 5.7.6, you can also increase the page size to
>   32KB or 64KB. For more information, refer to the innodb_page_size
>   documentation.
>
> The pages are grouped into extents of size 1MB for pages up to 16KB in
>   size (64 consecutive 16KB pages, or 128 8KB pages, or 256 4KB pages).
>   For a page size of 32KB, extent size is 2MB. For page size of 64KB,
>   extent size is 4MB. The “files” inside a tablespace are called
>   segments in InnoDB. (These segments are different from the rollback
>   segment, which actually contains many tablespace segments.)
>
> When a segment grows inside the tablespace, InnoDB allocates the first
>   32 pages to it one at a time. After that, InnoDB starts to allocate
>   whole extents to the segment. InnoDB can add up to 4 extents at a time
>   to a large segment to ensure good sequentiality of data.
>
> Two segments are allocated for each index in InnoDB. One is for
>   nonleaf nodes of the B-tree, the other is for the leaf nodes. Keeping
>   the leaf nodes contiguous on disk enables better sequential I/O
>   operations, because these leaf nodes contain the actual table data.

Comment: I think I saw that page of the docs before; this time I read it twice and followed all the links; I still can't see what it's telling me. I understand there is empty overhead when an extent is first added, but it appears the empty space here would not exceed 1 extent for a given table ... and it would appear I would not benefit from reducing the page size from default 16k to 8k or 4k, since in these cases the extent size remains the same.

Basically, I still think I'm missing something ... surely nobody would take mySQL seriously if the tables were always size >500% of the actual data?

Comment: I think you should read it again: "InnoDB can add up to **4 extents at a time** to a large segment to ensure good sequentiality of data". And you absolutely ignored the rationale why innodb does this: to make sure that the file is less fragmented. The last thin you are forgetting is that your tables are very small, therefore if innodb increases the file size by let's say 4mb, then it seems to be a large difference. If you have tables of several GBs, then 4mb additional space will not even register on your radar.

Comment: Ok, but 4 extents is still just 4MB which is far less than the bloat for these files ... but let's try some larger tables. I'm using the same table definition and just adding more records: For a table with 35MB of data, table size is 66MB = 90% overhead. For a table with 175MB of data the table size is 287MB = 64% overhead. Qualitatively speaking, the situation seems just as bad/silly/strange. What's going on?

Comment: You missed the part that the increase is done by **segment**, not by overall file size. Indexes are also stored in the table.

Comment: I didn't exactly miss it, although it's a stretch to say I understand it ... but the doc appears to be saying that I would have only 2 segments per table, one for data and one for the single index. Anyway, just the one question for now: Is 64% overhead "normal" for a table with 175MB of raw data?